# Throttling scroll in WebView to a max speed on iOS and Android

Tags: javascript, android, dom, webview, scroll

We have some render issues during webView scroll that are not tenable to fix programatically. We have tried all scenarios. FastDOM, shrinking the DOM to our best possible limiting, lazy loading etc. We archive some of the DOM tree but decided if we can get a delta and set a maximal user initiated scroll speed the reflow and repaints will have ample time to render before hitting the viewport. We tried this fiddle but due to mousewheel we can't get it to work in webview. Any tips would be grateful http://jsfiddle.net/36dp03ur/

```
if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', 
wheel, false);
window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;

function wheel(event) {
    var delta = 0;
    if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
    else if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 3;

    handle(delta);
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = false;
    }

    function handle(delta) {
    var time = 1000;
    var distance = 300;

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - (distance * delta)
    }, time );
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider overriding the touch handling on the Java side of the webview.

Comment: I will investigate this thank you. I couldn't add the iOS tag to this question but ideally, we want the max speed throttle (not to be confused with the throttle function, I just use the term for lack of a better word) to work on iOS too. The hard part is iOS prefers small/many tiles for webview, and Android the exact opposite, large and fewer and about the size of viewport.

Comment: Other idea is not to use native and make a custom inertia override. So instead of touchScroll (css paramater) remove it and handle the momentum with Javascript as we can then control the speed.